# Instagram could not login

Tags: instagram, account-recovery, instagram-account

My phone and sim is lost . I cannot login to my Instagram account as verification code is sent to sim which I have deactivated and to my mail ID which I cannot access. How can login to my Instagram

Answer (score 0):

Can you reset your email  password by chance? Or  perhaps a forgotten 2fa?
if not Cancel the old SIM

Get the provider to provide a new SIM, or, if you switched providers, “port” your old number to your new account

Log in to Instagram as usual.

If you want to continue to use your new number, you may need a temporary account to hold your old one for a bit.